# How to import screenlets on Python

Tags: python

**(I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 with `Linux 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:10:02 UTC 2010 i686`)**

For some reason I had updated some Python files (I'm not able to tell which ones, but it was during the installation of [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/)).

After that I noticed that my screenlets had disappeared after rebooting.

I'm trying to make screenlets work again since 3 days. I removed Hugin and everything related with `python3`. I have

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```

When I try to call `screenlets` I got

```
$ screenlets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/screenlets-manager/screenlets-manager.py", line 34, in <module>
    import screenlets
ImportError: No module named screenlets
```

I'm Googling for hours to find a solution but anything is working.  Helps are appreciated.

Comment: sound like when you upgrade, some packages had conflict and screenlets had been removed by some packages.

Comment: you can watch `/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, there are many python entries. Since there are python2.6 entries do you think that my older python version was less than 2.6?

Comment: no, but i don't know why you want to use import it.

Comment: I'm trying to run `screenlets` but as I wrote some `py` file is trying to import something.

Comment: add it to module path.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh, sorry but I have no idea how to do that neither where the module could be. Please, could you send me the terminal command to do that?

Comment: at first you should your write a module then add it to `PYTHONPATH`, however if your executable file import your module and your module is in your executable file, your don't need to add to pythonpath, any way you need to read http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm